# If I'm not using wordpress how do I use a premade amazon links in my website?

Tags: html

I am creating an ecommerce store that sells coffee using amazon affiliate links. I want to use the premade links that amazon gives you.

I've tried the obvious solution of copying and pasting the code into my HTML, but nothing appears when I copy the  element into my index.html

All the tutorials I've found are for how to use amazon links in wordpress or youtube but I am creating my own website from scratch, so  can put it in my portfolio and get hired.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='product_link'>
            <iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref=qf_sp_asin_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=michaelsteven-20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B071WWBKDY&asins=B071WWBKDY&linkId=0d2a7fc755c7a536feb9394bdc228be2&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I haven't worked with iframe before, but I tried changing iframe to div and that didn't fix it.

Comment: Divs can't load other HTML in this way. So you just want to use iframes for now. Does the URL in the `src` work when you load it in the browser in its own tab? If so, your iframe isn't showing the content within (needs better styling), if not, than there is something wrong with the URL.

Comment: I copy pasted the URL into google and it took me to the properly styled product link. When I click refresh on my html page it attempts to load the image but it briefly shows the sad paper icon.

Comment: Works fine here actually: https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/w8xodpgy/.

Comment: When I removed the '//' at the beginning of the url, it seemed to display just fine.

Comment: I tried fiddle and it doesn't work for me, the styled link doesn't appear... Maybe there's something different about my computer? I'm using chrome what browser are you using?

Comment: Do you see errors in the dev tools? If so, what errors do you see?

Comment: Lajos - there were no errors, now I've figured out that it was adblock preventing the link from displaying!

Comment: @games247 okay, I'm glad it was sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work fine, copying this into your page should get a result.
An iframe will copy the resulting html (from the link) into an element.

The link you have provided uses http, and not https, so you might have an issue bringing it in, as the browser sees it as unsecure. You can read more about the issue here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content.

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='product_link'>
        <iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref=qf_sp_asin_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=michaelsteven-20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B071WWBKDY&asins=B071WWBKDY&linkId=0d2a7fc755c7a536feb9394bdc228be2&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay this question prompted me to think outside the box. I've turned off adblock on my index.html and now the link appears............... So that raises the question, How do I make sure other people can see the link if they have adblock on?

Answer (score 0):

I turned off adblock and now the link appears! But that raises the question, How do I make sure these links appear when other people visit my site?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you would figure that out you would make literal billions.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='product_link'>
        <iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=US&source=ac&ref=qf_sp_asin_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=michaelsteven-20&marketplace=amazon&region=US&placement=B071WWBKDY&asins=B071WWBKDY&linkId=0d2a7fc755c7a536feb9394bdc228be2&show_border=true&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

this works fine, just remove the // from your link.

Comment: Why would it be a link? Its a page OP wants to show, to link to it.

Comment: The amazon links I want to use have more than just an image. I don't want to restyle all the text, borders and such.

Comment: Sorry I was confused I thought you wanted to style it yourself, see the edit above. Just remove // for your link.